# Pusher/Laravel echo error on subscribing to private channel: Auth value for subscription to channel is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I am having trouble subscribing to a private channel with PusherJS which is in **React application**.

Backend is Laravel but I am pretty sure the **backend/frontend** technologies **do not contribute** to this problem.

I am using **JWT** tokens for authentication and everything seems to be working on that part. The whole application is running fine but I am trying to add a socket to the system.

I will provide my backend and frontend code snippets here as I am pretty sure the fault lies in of them.

**Frontend**

```
const Socket = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: config.pusher.key,
  cluster: config.pusher.cluster,
  authEndpoint: config.pusher.authEndpoint,
  forceTLS: config.pusher.tls,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  },
});

Socket.private('users.1').listen('newMessage', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

**Backend auth endpoint**

```
public function authorize(Request $request) {
    echo Pusher::socket_auth($request->get('channel_name'), $request->get('socket_id'));
    return;
}
```

The auth endpoint works, the data is returned as follows:

```
{auth: ":2535a2ea3a1ee8f461ceef3a95095518c0205949aa981e6f2xxxxx"}
```

In console I can see that frontend application has successfully connected pusher

> Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID xxxxxx.xxxxxx

But the subscribing has failed

> Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":":2535a2ea3a1ee8f461ceef3a95095518c0205949aa981e6f2xxxxx","channel":"private-users.1"}}
>
> Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to private-users.1 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}
>
> Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to private-users.1 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}}

I tried using only **PusherJS package** and had the same problem. Now I tried using Laravel Echo and the result is the same.
Also what's important is that when I subscribe to a non private channel, the subscribing works and I can successfully receive the messages through the channel.

Pusher debug log only tells me the same thing:

> Auth value for subscription to private-users.1 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'

I have been debugging this for a few hours and I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: have you solve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Your auth endpoint does not appear to be responding correctly. Are your key, secret, and appID correctly configured server side? How about the Cluster? Is this correctly configured server and client side?

Comment: That might be true, but I believe I have done everything the way documentation tells me to: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints. But right I just saw that my first character of the auth string is ":". I'm looking into it. And what do you mean by Cluster

Comment: When you create an app in Pusher, you get to decide what area of the world your app operates from. By default, it will automatically stick your app in the Pusher MT1 region which is in the US. If you go to your pusher dashboard and look for your app credentials, you should see which cluster your app is configured within. You must then specify this in the client and server.